# Issue in writing the dictionary into YAML file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml, openstack-heat

I want to write dictionary into YAML file and here is what I'm doing as of now

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

Flavor_Details = {'Flavor_Details':{
                  'type': 'OS::Nova::Flavor', 
                  'properties': {
                                 'name': 'test-flavor', 
                                 'extra_specs': {"hw:cpu_policy": 'shared'}, 
                                 'ram': 4096, 
                                 'vcpus': 4, 
                                 'disk': 8
                                }
                 }}

output_section = {
                    'server_public_ip':{
                        'description': 'Floating IP address of server',
                        'value': { 'get_attr': [ 'server_floating_ip', 'ip' ] }
                    }
                }

resources_dict = {}
resources_dict.update(Flavor_Details)
resources_dict.update(output_section)

yaml = YAML(typ= 'safe')

with open('test.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
     yaml.dump(resources_dict,outfile)
```

And here is the result in YAML file

```
Flavor_Details:
    properties:
      disk: 8
      extra_specs: {hw:cpu_policy: shared}
      name: test-flavor
      ram: 4096
      vcpus: 4
    type: OS::Nova::Flavor
server_public_ip:
    description: Floating IP address of server
    value:
      get_attr: [server__floating_ip, ip]
```

But I wanted the result like this:

```
Flavor_Details:
    properties:
      disk: 8
      extra_specs: {"hw:cpu_policy": shared}
      name: test-flavor
      ram: 4096
      vcpus: 4
    type: OS::Nova::Flavor
server_public_ip:
    description: Floating IP address of server
    value: {get_attr: [server__floating_ip, ip]}
```

I wanted the `"hw:cpu_policy"` as a string because of the `:` between the `hw` and the `cpu_policy` and in the `value` I wanted to be like `{get_attr: [server__floating_ip, ip]}` this.

Is there any way to get things like that?

Comment: did you try escaping it `'{\\"foo\\": \\"bar\\"}'`?

Comment: That is never going to work. A string with quotes can be represented in YAML, but since the quotes itself have special meaning (at least at the beginning of a scalar) you'll get a single quoted scalar with embedded double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want, but not by using the safe dumper. The underlying C based code doesnt' allow
for the fine grained control that you want.

You'll need to use the default (round-trip) dumper, which allows for this kind of
detailed control, as it needs it to try-and-preserve the layout on round-trips.

I hope you realise that the quotes around `hw:cpu_policy` in the YAML file are
not necessary according to the YAML specification, but there are some incorrect
implementations of YAML parser that have problems with that.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def Q(s):
    return ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString(s)

def F(*args, **kw):
    x = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
    x.fa.set_flow_style()
    for a in args:
        x.update(a)
    x.update(kw)
    return x


Flavor_Details = {'Flavor_Details':{
                  'type': 'OS::Nova::Flavor', 
                  'properties': {
                                 'name': 'test-flavor', 
                                 'extra_specs': F({Q("hw:cpu_policy"): 'shared'}), 
                                 'ram': 4096, 
                                 'vcpus': 4, 
                                 'disk': 8
                                }
                 }}

output_section = {
                    'server_public_ip':{
                        'description': 'Floating IP address of server',
                        'value': F(get_attr=['server_floating_ip', 'ip'])
                    }
                }

resources_dict = {}
resources_dict.update(Flavor_Details)
resources_dict.update(output_section)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.dump(resources_dict, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
Flavor_Details:
  type: OS::Nova::Flavor
  properties:
    name: test-flavor
    extra_specs: {"hw:cpu_policy": shared}
    ram: 4096
    vcpus: 4
    disk: 8
server_public_ip:
  description: Floating IP address of server
  value: {get_attr: [server_floating_ip, ip]}
```

Comment: The inconsistent indentation of your mappings (4 spaces at the root level, 2 spaces underneath) cannot be achieved, but if you want you can change the indent with the commented out line

Comment: @DirtyBit I would hope so, I am rather familiar with that the ruamel.yaml package

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be going back to PyYAML and use a simple replacement rule on the output string. Note as well the *requoted* entries for `extra_specs` and `value`.

```
import yaml as yl

Flavor_Details = {'Flavor_Details': {
                  'type': 'OS::Nova::Flavor',
                  'properties': {
                      'name': 'cloudpeak-test-flavor',
                      'extra_specs': "{'hw:cpu_policy': shared}",
                      'ram': 4096,
                      'vcpus': 4,
                      'disk': 8
                  }
                  }}

output_section = {
    'server_public_ip': {
        'description': 'Floating IP address of server',
        'value': '{get_attr: [server_floating_ip, ip]}'
    }
}

resources_dict = {}
resources_dict.update(Flavor_Details)
resources_dict.update(output_section)

out_str = yl.safe_dump(resources_dict)
out_str = out_str.replace("''", '"')
out_str = out_str.replace("'", '')

print(out_str)

with open('test-yl.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(out_str)
```

which gives:

```
Flavor_Details:
  properties:
    disk: 8
    extra_specs: {"hw:cpu_policy": shared}
    name: cloudpeak-test-flavor
    ram: 4096
    vcpus: 4
  type: OS::Nova::Flavor
server_public_ip:
  description: Floating IP address of server
  value: {get_attr: [server_floating_ip, ip]}
```